# Why is the factor group $H/H_r$ cyclic with generator $hH_r$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I´m refering to the proof of thrm. 5.3, p.337 of this [paper](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Edrinfeld/Hypergeometric_motives/Beukers-Heckman.pdf).

In the setup of this proof we consider a group $H$  and a normal subgroup $H_r \trianglelefteq H$. Since $H_r$ is normal in $H$, the quotient group $H/H_r$ exists. What i don´t understand is, why this group should be cyclic with generator $hH_r$?

---

Now note, that the solution to this question would be easy, if we had that $H$ were cyclic with generator $h$, since the factor group of a cyclic group is cyclic. But unfortunately $H=\langle h_{\infty}, h_0^{-1} \rangle$ and in the beginning of the proof we choose $h$ to be either $h_{\infty}$ or $h_0^{-1}$. So unless we can (why ever possible) disregard one of the generators and get $H=\langle h \rangle$, i don´t see why this should hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h = h_0$ or $h = h_\infty$.

In the paper $H = \langle h_0, h_1, h_\infty \rangle$ with $h_\infty h_1h_0 = 1$, so $H = \langle h_1, h \rangle$.

Thus the quotient $H/H_r$ is generated by $h_1H_r$ and $hH_r$. But $h_1 \in H_r$, so $H/H_r$ is generated by $hH_r$.